# Edit the first INI file in path

Tags: delphi

My software uses a DLL, which is configured by an INI file. It gets the first one with a specific name (Bemafi32.ini if it matters) that it can find in the system path.

I want to add in my software the ability to edit this file. I don't want to get the wrong one if my system have two or more files with the same name (which is very, very common). How can I assure to get the proper file?

Comment: How exactly can you get a wrong one if there are two or more files with the same name in system, would not they be on different paths? You need a way to distinct your INI files. Either by name, or by path, or by contents. Without that you can't be sure which one you have accessed and edited.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.GetEnvironmentVariable http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.FileSearch

Comment: I don't know if my question was clear enough, but what I need is a way to, given a file name, get the first path that such file is located in the computer. Let's say I have bemafi32.ini in c:\, c:\mypath and c:\windows. My application is located on c:\ but c:\mypath and c:\windows are both on system's path. Wich one will be first located? How can I get it programaticaly?

Comment: So, how does your DLL find the INI file? What function does it use to search over the `PATH` env var? I ask because I don't believe that your DLL is finding the INI file by searching the `PATH`. That's because the only functions that do that are `CreateProcess`, `LoadLibrary` and friends.

Comment: @David Heffernan, it is a third party propietary DLL.

Comment: @user539484, I guess your comment could better be an answer...

Comment: @RicardoAcras It's certainly the answer to the question that you asked, but it surely isn't the solution to your problem.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I can assume that the DLL does the same, at least empirically

Comment: Your assumption seems unlikely to be accurate. More plausible is that the DLL calls `GetModuleFileName` passing its module handle and then looks for the INI file in the same directory. It would be somewhat dodgy to rely on PATH lookup for configuration. Anything could happen! Am I right in thinking that the DLL is in the system path, and the INI file is always in the same directory as the DLL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the first INI file on the path, then use [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16200673/33732) with `FileSearch` and `GetEnvironmentVariable`. It's more likely that the DLL uses the INI file that resides in the same directory as itself, rather than the first one on the path. Otherwise, *all* copies of the DLL would use the *same* INI file because the path is generally the same for all processes.

To get the INI file in the same directory as the DLL, you need to know where the DLL is, and that could require knowing which copy of the DLL you'll load. That's not the easiest thing to figure out, so you can shift the burden to the OS:

1. Load the DLL yourself with `LoadLibrary`. The OS will use its normal search algorithm to find the DLL.
2. Call `GetModuleFileName` to find out the path of the DLL you loaded.
3. Open the INI file in the same directory as the DLL.

(If your program has already loaded the DLL because it *uses* the DLL, then you can call `GetModuleHandle` instead of `LoadLibrary`.)

Comment: Well, empirically I found that the DLL first try to load the ini file in the same directory that it resides on and if it doesn't find it there than it will search the path. So I'll use both answeres to get to the solution.

Answer (score 4):

> @user539484, I guess your comment could better be an answer...

No problem, I can make it an **answer**, but it will be a **solution** only if you are really sure what your DLL behaves exactly as you described in the question. Remember, [DLL search strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682586) is little more complex than just locating first matching file in `PATH`.

```
var
  IniPathName: TFileName;
begin
  IniPathName := FileSearch('Bemafi32.ini', GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH')); { do not localize }
  Assert(IniPathName <> '', 'Unable to locate file');
  { ... }
```

#### Reference:

- [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.GetEnvironmentVariable)
- [`FileSearch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.FileSearch)

Comment: +1 My point is that even if DLL search was that simple, then looking for the INI file in the PATH would not be the same as looking for the INI file in the same folder as the DLL.

Comment: Indeed it was not the whole solution, but it is part of the solution, hence my suggestion to be an answer. +1 for that, but accepted @Rob Kennedy's answere as the final solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Ricardo Acras, it is solution for your given specs, which were proven incorrect in the process. That's why I gave you information in the form of comment.